# Android App context for singleton at Shared preferences

Tags: android, memory-leaks, sharedpreferences

I wanna refactor my project and it has a lot of unnecessary code with hardcoded string. So I wanted to create singleton SharedPrefsManager, i will use Application context. does it occur memory leak cause of static SharedPrefs in my manager class.

```
public class SharedPrefsManager {

    private static SharedPrefsManager sharePref = new SharedPrefsManager();
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private SharedPrefsManager() {} 


    public static SharedPrefsManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        return sharePref;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you need an instance of the class if the thing you're after is `static` in it as well. Make the `SharedPreferences` non-static.

Comment: Application context will live as long as your application is alive and does not depend on the activities life cycle , so no memory leaks in this case

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not get any memory Leak if you use an application context. Create the `SharedPrefsManager` as a singleton and Initialize from your `Application` class. so that you can access from anywhere

Create like this,

```
public class SharedPrefsManager {
    private static SharedPrefsManager mInstance= null;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

    private SharedPrefsManager(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        mInstance = new SharedPrefsManager(context);

    }


    public static SharedPrefsManager getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Must run init(Application application) before an instance can be obtained");
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * To get the Stored string value in Preference.
     *
     * @param key
     * @param defaultvalue
     * @return stored string value.
     */
    public String getStringValue(final String key, final String defaultvalue) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultvalue);
    }

    /**
     * To store the string value in prefernce.
     *
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public void setStringValue(final String key, final String value) {
        prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

From Application class you can initialize like this,

```
public class StackApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPrefsManager.init(this);
    }
}
```

So that you can use from any other class without context.
Ex: you can use like this,

```
SharedPrefsManager.getInstance().setStringValue("key", "value");
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the answer is bad cause you're not using getInstance which is the point of a singleton :D

Comment: I just initialize the class, I never used that, while you use, you should call ** SharedPrefsManager.getInstance().setstring("key", "value");** that is the main purpose of the example i gave

Comment: I added example how we should use the class in my answer, have a look. If this is bad, you can suggest me, and u can also add an answer so that everyone will get use from that.

Comment: But there is no memory-leak problem in holding SharedPreferences in static because it doesn't use context. You need context just to obtain them

Comment: @PotapovAnton, I never said it will lead to memory-leak check my answer.

Comment: @Muthukrishnan Rajendran yep. And in this case you don't need to init in Application class. Just pass w context to getInstance(). Your code will cause an error if it's used in BroadcastReceiver. Application#onCreate is not called in this case.

Comment: The main purpose of calling init in application class is I don't want to send context while calling getInstance, I would like to call from anywhere from my App. And more over I don't want to argue more, I am using this class from last 8 years in my Android apps, I never got any issue in memory, I just felt useful so I shared, I you felt its very bad logic, let me know how can I improve, Let me think of change that, if your answer is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Holding `SharedPreferences` in static field doesn't provoke memory leaks because Preferences doesn't contain `Context` itself